# shared preference stored value check and display a widget

Tags: flutter

I'm storing an id and a bool value using shared preference when a button click in a container.Next time when I come to that screen I need to check that saved id and the bool value with the id of that container and not to show the container if the ids are same.Container is wrapped with a visibility to hide it when clicked.

```
bool isVisible = true;

Visibility(
    visible: isVisible,
    child: Container(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('Click'),
        onPressed: () async {
           SharedPreferences prefs =
                                await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                            setState(() {
                              isVisible = false;
                              prefs.setBool('container', false);
                              prefs.setInt('Id', container.id);
                            });
                          },
      
        ),
    ));
```

Comment: Load it before the `runApp` call

Comment: I disagree with @AlexRintt's statement. Initializing datas before the ```runApp``` statement should only be done in order to init part of the code required by the ```MaterialApp``` (e.g. Phrase, a translation library), or part of the code requiring an asynchronous init which will be used in the whole app (e.g. a Database service, Crashlytics etc...)

Answer (score -1):

I'll assume you're not using a State Management library.

You could wrap this `Visibility` widget in a StatefulWidget, fetch the datas from your sharedPreferences in the `initState` method, and refresh your screen with a `setState`

Another solution would be to use a `FutureBuilder`, which is better for your current use-case in my opinion.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: isVisible(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Visibility(
                  visible: snapshot.data ?? true,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      //Whatever you need
                    },
                    child: const Text('Click'),
                  ),
                );
              }

              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return const Text("Error");
              }

              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> isVisible() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final containerId = prefs.getInt('Id');
    final containerVisibility = prefs.getBool('container');

    //Do your stuff and return the bool you want
    return true;
  }
}
```